# tcp server accepting only some connections

Tags: sockets, tcp, erlang, gen-tcp

I have a tcp server and a client. The client spawns 1000 processes each trying to connect to the tcp server. I can see that the tcp server is accepting 245 connections and rejecting all the rest. Every time, the server is accepting the first 245.

Fixes:
Tried to increase the backlog attribute but did not work.
Tried to call timer:sleep(N) after each process spawn so that I can reduce the rate at which tcp server can accept clients. Failed!

Server and client:

```
 accept(LSocket) ->
   case gen_tcp:accept(LSocket) of
     {ok, Socket} ->
       io:format("Accepted ~n"),
       {sockets, List} = hd(ets:lookup(csockets, sockets)),
       NewList = [Socket | List],
       ets:insert(csockets, {sockets, NewList}),
       Pid = spawn(fun() ->
        loop(Socket, 0)
              end),
       gen_tcp:controlling_process(Socket, Pid),
       accept(LSocket);
     {error, closed} ->
       error
    end.
```

Client:

```
    send(State = #state{low = Low, high = Low}) ->
      NewState = receive_sockets(0, Low, State),
      NewState;
      send(State = #state{low = Low}) ->
      N = Low rem 2,
      Dest = lists:nth(2, State#state.dest),
      loop(self(), Dest, Low),
      NewState = State#state{low = Low + 1},
      send(NewState).

   loop(From, {IP, Port}, Low) ->
     case gen_tcp:connect(IP, Port, []) of
      {ok, Socket} ->
        gen_tcp:send(Socket, integer_to_binary(Low)),
        From ! {Low, Socket},
        Pid = spawn(?MODULE, receive_from_other_users, []),
        gen_tcp:controlling_process(Socket, Pid);
      _Else ->
        io:format("The connection failed ~n"),
        loop(From, {IP, Port}, Low)
   end.
```

Comment: There are four fail error code:Reason = closed | timeout | system_limit | inet:posix(). It's better to capture the specify error code, then it tell you the root cause. The implement in the server side should improve a little. In the situation rather than {ok, Socket} the server stop accept connection, lead new incoming connections rejected.

Comment: You either need to provide the exact error return values you're getting, or you need to post enough code so that others can run it themselves. You should also include details of what OS you're on and how it's configured with respect to max file descriptors and other settings that affect TCP-based applications.

Comment: I used ulimit -n to see that only 256 are allowed. I am using OSX.